# What distribution other than Bernouli can be defined on a binary variable?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, machine-learning

Can there be any distribution different from Bernouli on a binary variable?

Context: I am trying to understand if logistic regression uses any statistical assumption that can be false on some data set with IID examples.
It looks like it does not, but perhaps answering the above question makes it more clear.

Comment: Standard binary logistic or ordinal logistic? Logistic can be done between non-continuous data sometimes, in some cases by finding underlying latent variables.

Comment: I'd say that the Bernoulli distribution is defined as the distribution of a binary random variable.

Comment: @gary Standard binary logistic regression.

Comment: @user25004:If I understood you correctly, we could also have a geometric distribution on a binary variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $Y_i\in\{0,1\}$. Then we have completely characterized $Y_i$ by specifying $$P(Y_i=0)=p_i$$ because it forces $P(Y_i=1)=1-p_i$. The probability mass function completely specifies the random variable, so there is only one parameter for a specific $i$, which is $p_i$.
Furthermore, you said the variables are IID, so $p_i=p\;\forall\;i$. But this is exactly a Bermoulli distribution. So that's really the only option.

However, for logistic regression, I tend to think of it as trying to construct a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \{0,1\}$. You feed it vectors $X_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (with components $x_{ij}$), and try to predict the correct label $\mathfrak{y}_i=\ell(X_i)$. Here are there are many assumptions, beyond the normal IID assumption on the data. For instance, logistic regression is a *linear* model: it does not assume that the features and labels are linearly related, but it does assume that the relation between the features and the log-odds of the labels *are* linearly related. 
It assumes that $P(\mathfrak{y}|X)$ is Bermoulli (whereas linear regression tends to assume $P(\mathfrak{y}|X)$ is Gaussian).
It also assumes that the error terms are independent  and that there is no [multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity).
Note that these *assumptions* do not mean that logistic regression *won't work* without it; it just won't work *as well* as theory would predict.